# send_Keys to selenium python, not working. How to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

My xpath validates in PyCharm but when I try to use send _key I get an error.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver 2')
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath = '//*[@id=username'
username.send_keys('username')
```

`'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`

the above error is given when I try to send keys, otherwise, it works fine. Can anyone assist me with this?

Would importing a package solve this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `username = driver.find_element_by_xpath = '//*[@id=username'` with `username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=username]')`

`find_element_by_xpath` is a method, not an attribute (well, technically it is still an attribute because in Python, functions are first-class objects). What you effectively did is reassign the function `find_element_by_xpath` from a function object to the string `'//*[@id=username'`, then assign that value to `username`. Therefore, you called the `send_keys` method on a string, e.g. `'//*[@id=username'.send_keys('username')`. While you have not included the whole code, I assume you do not need to include any packages as it seems to have not thrown an exception before reaching the last line.

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance.

I tried this before but it then I was getting the exception -

`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id=username because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id=username' is not a valid XPath expression.`

....which I think I may have just solved by copying the full xpath as opposed to just xpath.

What is the difference between the two and why does one work and not the other.

Comment: I was mainly concerned with solving the issue of `'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'` instead of fixing syntax errors - as it says. The error itself says the issue - you have a syntactically-invalid selector. The correct selector would be `//*[@id='username']`, as you have left out the closing square bracket `]` and not enclosed in quotation marks the string `username`.